# I have page not found 404 698K page what should i do

Tags: seo

I have page not found 404   698K page what should i do  it gonna affect seo in my website ? [image]

Comment: We need more information.  You need to find out an example of the page

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The result of 698,000 URLs returning 404 (not found) will be the following:

1. Any of the URLs that have already been indexed, will cease to be indexed, because they no longer exist.
2. Any of the URLs the urls that are not indexed, will not be, because they can't be crawled.
3. Search Engines may lose trust in your website.

Absent of some justifying factor that warrants these URLs to not exist (404 sitemaps can be effective), the affect on your website's SEO will likely be negative. With over half a million 404 errors present, your SEO may be considered "Bad" if judged based on adherence to best practices.

Side note:

While "bad" and "negative" can sometimes be understood to mean the same thing in general usage, those at SEMrush have steadfastly defined "Negative SEO" as the following:

> Negative SEO (sometimes known as adverse SEO) is a malicious attempt to harm a business’s visibility in search engine results, typically with the aim of stealing its keyword rankings and traffic.

Source: [What Is Negative SEO?](https://www.semrush.com/blog/what-is-negative-seo/)

### Why are 404 errors "bad" for SEO?

Here's some context via [IONOS](https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/websites/website-creation/what-does-the-404-not-found-error-mean/):

> Search engines, such as Google and Bing, will have a negative impression of a site if it has many 404 errors. Once the crawlers have established that many requests are being met with 404 codes, it presumes the site isn’t very well maintained. Dead links affect a site’s ranking and Google can decrease its placement in the SERPs or even stop indexing it if there are too many 404 error pages occurring. This may result in a considerable decrease in visitor numbers for the website.

Comment: Mike, I always appreciate reading your comments.  This does raise a question though.  What should be done about 404 created by external sites?